# ASP.NET MVC 5 Membership impersonate specific user

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

There are many examples about impersonating a user in c# but the thing is you have to provide the domain, username and password of that user.

What I need is a bit different. If we build an app in ASP.NET MVC 5 using membership, let's assume we have the following roles in place:

- Admin
- User
- Visitor

and users whom belong to different roles.

Now if a user from role `User` has some issues with the application, how can I allow a user from `Admin` role to impersonate that specific user, without that specific user to give the Admin his username and password?

The main thing is that the `Admin` should be able to impersonate any user from the application and be able to browse the application as the user himself.

Is this possible to achieve in MVC?

There are many applications out there that offer this possibility, one of them is Salesforce. And Admin in Salesforce can impersonate any user, and browse/see the application as the user himself. This will allow them to identify and solve possible problems in the application.

Comment: See my blog-post: http://tech.trailmax.info/2014/06/user-impersonation-with-asp-net-identity-2/

Comment: MVC really doesn't have anything to do with this.  MVC just uses whatever user is currently in the HttpContext.Current.Identity global value.  All you have to do is reset this in the same way that you set it for any other user, just don't bother to check the password if they are already known to be an administrator.  However, let me caution you that doing this may violate laws, or create problems for compliance with various regulations or policies such as HIPPA, PCI, Sarbanes-Oxley, etc...  Check with lawyers before you do this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Now if a user from role User has some issues with the application, how
>   can I allow a user from Admin role to impersonate that specific user,
>   without that specific user to give the Admin his username and
>   password? ...Is this possible to achieve in MVC?

This can be accomplished without knowing the password of the user to be impersonated, but you do have to know the username of the user to be impersonated.

You can do this with the following using normal Forms Authentication:

```
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie("username-to-be-impersonated", false);
```

Of course you would want to protect the entry to this block of code, so that only admins can do the impersonation. You will probably want to do something else like save the admin user's username in session or cookie to help the system know that an impersonation is in progress, and give the user the ability to reverse it when they are done impersonating.

Bottom line is, all the membership system cares about is the auth cookie, and you can write an auth cookie for any username without knowing the user's password.

The process is the same for ASP.NET Identity 2, the difference is just how you write the auth cookie. Note the code below is [a snippet based on the comment that @trailmax left in the OP](http://tech.trailmax.info/2014/06/user-impersonation-with-asp-net-identity-2/):

```
// assume you already have references to a UserManager and HttpContext
var userToImpersonate = await userManager
    .FindByNameAsync(userNameToImpersonate);
var identityToImpersonate = await userManager
    .CreateIdentityAsync(userToImpersonate,   
        DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
var authenticationManager = httpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication;
authenticationManager.SignOut(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
authenticationManager.SignIn(new AuthenticationProperties()
{
    IsPersistent = false
}, identityToImpersonate);
```

You should also have a policy that allows you to somehow get the user's permission before having an admin impersonate their account.

Comment: Sounds good! Of course the requirements are a bit more complex and all the impersonation will be done properly by checking that the Admin is really an Admin and another thing is that the Admin will not be able to impersonate the user without the user permissions. Basically something like this: `I am a User of this application and I have a problem! I allow Admin roles to impersonate me and check/see the problem I can see! Admin roles user can then impersonate that specific user. User can cancel the impersonation permissions and can set a date and time for impersonation, like for next 4h only.`

Comment: @DavidDury then it sounds like you were just looking for how to write the authentication cookie. As far as MVC is concerned, that is all that matters as far as identifying the user and setting the Controller.User IPrincipal instance. You only need to know the username to set this cookie, not the password.

Comment: Yeap that's correct. That part was a bit of a `black hole`. Thank you and to @trailmax for the blog post!

Answer (score 3):

I don't think the solution lies in the membership system itself.  I would probably implement the impersonation within the application logic.  The membership system tells you the identity of the user and what roles they have, but your application is free to ignore or interpret those roles as you like.

EDIT: To elaborate...

You can look at this not as an issue with membership but simply as a set of features built into the application.  An administrator has the ability to see what a user sees simply by being an administrator - this is build into the application logic.

Trying to hack this feature into the membership system so the application is somehow fooled into treating the administrator as a different member seems hacky - and any abuse of the membership system is going to open up security holes.

If you really wanted to go down this route perhaps you should look at giving administrators short term tokens tied to their IP address for say 10 mins that let them login as anyone - again this isn't tied to membership - it's tied to password checking which you can factor out.

So I'm not really giving a solution here - just suggesting that it's not to be found in hacking the underlying membership system.  If you do this then you weaken the security of the membership system but you also limit what you can achieve.  For example maybe you want to show administrators what users see + some extra information for diagnostics - if the application thinks the administrator is a user how would this work?

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit your answer?

Comment: I disagree that this can be hacky, and it does not weaken the security of the membership system if done correctly. Sometimes such a feature is very helpful to be able to see exactly what another non-admin user sees. And it can be necessary if you have actions with usernames or user id's in the route, as there is usually not a good way to open up those actions to admin users with a different username or user id.

Answer (score 0):

All I do is pass the current user id in a session and read the session throughout the application. If the current logged in user is different from the session object I know impersonation is going on. I set all this in the global.asax file on session start. Seems to work great for my apps.